# Find coordinate by angle

Tags: c#, graphing

I am developing in application in XNA which draws random paths.  Unfortunately, I'm out of touch with graphing, so I'm a bit stuck.  My application needs to do the following:

1. Pick a random angle from my origin (0,0), which is simple.
2. Draw a circle in relation to that origin, 16px away (or any distance I specify), at the angle found above.

(Excuse my horrible photoshoping)

[alt text http://www.refuctored.com/coor.png](http://www.refuctored.com/coor.png)

The second circle at (16,16) would represent a 45 degree angle 16 pixels away from my origin.

I would like to have a method in which I pass in my distance and angle that returns a point to graph at. i.e.

```
private Point GetCoordinate(float angle, int distance)
{
   // Do something.
   return new Point(x,y);
}
```

I know this is simple, but agian, I'm pretty out of touch with graphing.  Any help?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the angle is in degrees, first do:

```
angle *= Math.PI / 180;
```

Then:

```
return new Point(distance * Math.Cos(angle), distance * Math.Sin(angle));
```

By the way, the point at (16, 16) is not 16 pixels away from the origin, but sqrt(16^2 + 16^2) = sqrt(512) =~ 22.63 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Point GetCoordinate(float angle, int distance)
{
  float x = cos(angle) * distance;
  float y = sin(angle) * distance;
  return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Note that the trigonometric functions probably take radians. If your angle is in degrees, divide by 180/Pi.

Answer (score 0):

in general:

```
x = d * cos(theta)
y = d * sin(theta)
```

Where d is the distance from the origin and theta is the angle.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). Then [this thread](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/41789.aspx) should have more specific details for you.